# Updating users data when signed in with omniauth (twitter)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter, omniauth

I have no clue how could I manage to update the users data that signed up through Omniauth- For example, if I update my profil picture on twitter, then the profil picture on my web app is not updated and will appear broken.

My user model is set as following:

**app/models/user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_merit

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: :slugged
  def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
    new_record?
    end


  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,:omniauthable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

   validates :email, presence: true, 
                    uniqueness: true

  has_many :pins, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :votes, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :upvoted_pins, through: :votes, source: :pin

  has_many :rewards, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :rewarded_pins, through: :rewards, source: :pin

  has_many :badges






  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
  where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_create do |user|
    user.provider = auth.provider
    user.uid = auth.uid
    user.name = auth.info.nickname
    user.image = auth["info"]["image"]
    user.description = auth.info.description
  end
end

def self.new_with_session(params, session)
  if session["devise.user_attributes"]
    new(session["devise.user_attributes"]) do |user|
      user.attributes = params
      user.valid?
    end
  else
    super
  end
end

def password_required?
  super && provider.blank?
end

def update_with_password(params, *options)
  if encrypted_password.blank?
    update_attributes(params, *options)
  else
    super
  end
end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you can always check to see if the data needs to be updated. For example:

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def twitter_oauth2
    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])

    if @user.image != request.env["omniauth.auth"]["info"]["image"]
      @user.image = request.env["omniauth.auth"]["info"]["image"]
      @user.save
   ...
  end
end
```

Comment: Hey I tried a lot of things to implement this but it is still now working - I cant get te profile picture updated with omniauth ... any ideas?